# Does the Atlas path end after you have turned in the 10 stones?

Tags: no-mans-sky

[WARNING: SPOILERS AHEAD]

I have just recently turned in the 10 Atlas Stones after following the Atlas path but it seems to me that the game has now sort of "ended", meaning all I can do now is explore and go wherever I want? While following the Atlas path I have always gotten a prompt to continue towards a certain goal/direction.
But after turning in those 10 stones it seems to be the end of the path? I have not yet received any new message pointing me towards a new goal...

Is this how it is supposed to go and should I go and find Nada to follow one of the other paths or is it a new bug?

Comment: I haven't gotten that far yet but from what I understand, yes, that's the end of the Atlas path. Now you either go free exploring the cosmos, or start making your way to the center of the galaxy.

Comment: Ok, but then where will I get the upgraded Atlas passes from? I received the first one from the Atlas and thought I would receive the upgrades as well but so far only have v1 but if the path is over I will get it from other sources?

Comment: The other Atlas passes come from other sources, not the Atlas path. You can find them randomly as blueprints - I think mining facilities have the biggest chance of dropping them, but I'm not sure on that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, this is how it is **supposed** to end. As you now have access to the location of all the black holes on your galactic map, though, I advise asking for resources from Nada in the future, and just giving Polo whatever he asks for. You can find the upgraded Atlas Passes in things such as Manufacturing Facilities and Operation Centres, as well as in random crates.

Some people complained about the lack of an ending cutscene and direction, but that is how the Atlas Path finishes - learning about Black Holes and being send away.

Centre of the Galaxy Spoiler:

> As far as I've seen, there is also no Atlas Path in the second Galaxy, and the only way to get to the centre is via black holes and warping.

Comment: Pretty disappointing ending ...

Comment: @Mr.Meeseeks Yes, some people were complaining about it on gamefaqs, I think. I can't find the thread again though, sadly.